# Java recursive code not returning expected result

Tags: java, recursion

Below is code that does not return when and what I expected. I've included output with debug messages. Thanks for taking the time to review what I've done.

```
package module4;

import java.nio.charset.spi.CharsetProvider;
import java.util.Scanner;

public class LabRecursive{

    public static void main(String[] args) {

        // Prompt user and call the method
        Scanner s = new Scanner(System.in);
        System.out.print("Enter a string: ");
        String var = s.next();
        System.out.println("There is/are " + vowels(var, 0, 0) + " vowel(s) in the string " + var);
        s.close();

    }

    public static int vowels(String input, int currentPos, int amount) {
        // Create the arrays of chars to hold vowels and the input
        System.out.println("Amount at beginning: " + amount);
        char[] vow = {'a', 'e', 'i', 'o', 'u'};        
        char[] entered = input.toLowerCase().toCharArray();
        int stringLength = input.length();

        System.out.println("stringlength " + stringLength);

        if (currentPos < stringLength) {
            for (int i=0; i<5; i++) {
                if (entered[currentPos] == vow[i]) {
                    amount++;
                    System.out.println("vowel: " + entered[currentPos]);
                    System.out.println("amount: " + amount);
                    continue;
                }
            }

                currentPos++;
                System.out.println("Amount before calling the recursive function: " + amount);
                System.out.println("currentPos before calling the recursive function: " + currentPos);
                vowels(input, currentPos, amount);       
        }

        System.out.println("Amount before returning the final amount: " + amount);
        return amount;
    }   
}
```

> Enter a string: ijo
>
> Amount at beginning: 0
>
> stringlength 3
>
> vowel: I
>
> amount: 1
>
> Amount before calling the recursive function: 1
>
> currentPos before calling the recursive function: 1
>
> Amount at beginning: 1
>
> stringlength 3
>
> Amount before calling the recursive function: 1
>
> currentPos before calling the recursive function: 2
>
> Amount at beginning: 1
>
> stringlength 3
>
> vowel: o
>
> amount: 2
>
> Amount before calling the recursive function: 2
>
> currentPos before calling the recursive function: 3
>
> Amount at beginning: 2
>
> stringlength 3
>
> Amount before returning the final amount: 2
>
> Amount before returning the final amount: 2
>
> Amount before returning the final amount: 1
>
> Amount before returning the final amount: 1
>
> There is/are 1 vowel(s) in the string ijo

Comment: What's the expected result and what do you think isn't working? Please elaborate

Comment: You're not doing anything with the result of the recursive call - you call your `vowels` method but you don't store or return the result: `vowels(input, currentPos, amount);`

Comment: Thanks for answering. "amount = vowels(input, currentPos, amount);"  worked.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This change ought to fix this.

```
vowels(input, currentPos, amount);
```

to

```
amount = vowels(input, currentPos, amount);
```

Comment: Thanks for your help. "amount = vowels(input, currentPos, amount);"  worked.

Answer (score 0):

To improve speed and make better usage of the recursive method.
All input parameters can even be read only.

```
public static int vowels(final String input, final int currentPos, final int amount) {
    // Create the arrays of chars to hold vowels and the input
    System.out.println("Amount at beginning: " + amount);
    char[] vow = {'a', 'e', 'i', 'o', 'u'};        
    char[] entered = input.toLowerCase().toCharArray();
    int stringLength = input.length();

    System.out.println("stringlength " + stringLength);

    if (currentPos < stringLength) {
        for (int i=0; i<5; i++) {
            if (entered[currentPos] == vow[i]) {
                System.out.println("vowel: " + entered[currentPos]);
                System.out.println("amount: " + amount);
                return vowels(input, currentPos + 1, amount + 1); 
            }
        }

        System.out.println("Amount before calling the recursive function: " + amount);
        System.out.println("currentPos before calling the recursive function: " + currentPos);
        return vowels(input, currentPos + 1, amount);       
    }

    System.out.println("Amount before returning the final amount: " + amount);
    return amount;
}
```

Comment: Thanks for answering. "amount = vowels(input, currentPos, amount);"  worked.